# Vegas Pro blurring the edges of my sources

Tags: video-editor, vegas-pro

I am composing two 'Solid Color' media generator sources in Vegas Pro: a green background and a red rectangle on top of it (using Pan/Crop).

[image: Composition]

My goal is to have the edges of the red rectangle completely sharp, but no matter what I do, upon rendering I end up with a very annoying sort of anti-aliasing which creates a visibly black border at the edges.

[image: Blurred edges]

I have tried a handful of quality presets, rendering presets, turning GPU acceleration on or off, the result ends up roughly the same. It even renders this way if I use "save as an image" in the Preview window, despite the Preview showing sharp edges.

Comment: Have you tried rendering into a 4:4:4 format? Does it make a difference?